# Show that $ \mathbb P(A)=0 $ or $1$ for every $A\in \sigma(\Pi)$ independent of the $\pi$-system $\Pi$

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Suppose the event $A\in \sigma(\Pi)$  is independent of the $\pi$-system $\Pi$. Show $\mathbb P(A)=0$ or $1$.

It seems I need an equation $\mathbb P(A\cap A)=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(A)$. And I want to approximate $A$ with a sequence of sets in $\Pi$ so that their symmetric differences with $A$ goes to $0$. This works if $\Pi$ is an algebra, but I don't know how to proceed the case that $\Pi$ is only a $\pi$-system.

Comment: Hint: What do you know about the structure of the family C of events B such that A is independent of B? Now, you know that C contains Π, hence...

Comment: @Did, So $C$ is a sigma algebra?

Comment: Tell us. $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did Seems true to me, but I'm having trouble checking intersection and union ( I can show if the intersection is in the sigma algebra then so does the union, though)